# erro ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automatização

Boa tarde, o que significa o erro a seguir?

```
Class not found stancedriver.StanceDriver
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: stancedriver.StanceDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClass(RemoteTestRunner.java:688)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClasses(RemoteTestRunner.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

nao estou tentando fazer remotamente e o erro persiste

Comment: Significa que teu código precisou instanciar um objeto da classe StanceDriver mas não achou um import pra ele.

Comment: Bom seria bom você colocar seu código aqui para que pudesse verificar se contem erros, assim fica meio complicado dar uma resposta precisa mas ao que parece no log esta dando erro na criação do objeto driver que você usa para estanciar o navegador tenta debugar colocando sysout no codigo para ver por onde esta passando se nao conseguir coloca o seu Código aqui que te ajudo .

Answer (score -3):

Boa tarde Amigo,

Neste post explico o que significa está exception e também a diferença entre NoClassDefFoundError e ClassNotFoundException.
Acesse lá: https://edermfl.wordpress.com/2017/01/12/diferenca-entre-noclassdeffounderror-e-classnotfoundexception/
[]'s

---

Conforme orientação do Gabriel, segue explicação:

> ClassNotFoundException, acontece normalmente quando se usa reflexão.
>   Se existir um código que carrega uma classe usando Class.forName() ou
>   Class.class.getClassLoader().loadClass() e a classe não existir no
>   classpath, o erro é lançado. Neste caso, a classe procurada, não
>   precisa necessariamente ter sido compilada junto com a classe que à
>   referência.

Mais detalhe consulte: https://edermfl.wordpress.com/2017/01/12/diferenca-entre-noclassdeffounderror-e-classnotfoundexception/

Comment: Eder, recomendo colocar estas respostas aqui, porque os links podem ficar ficar inválidos com o tempo.